# Export a list of Report Server folders to a text file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, reporting-services

I'm new to using PowerShell so apologies if this is a rudimentary question.

I want to write some code that will list all the folders and folder paths on the Report Server, from the top level down, to a .txt file, one line per folder/path.  I will then edit this list before using it to dump the selected folders' .rdl contents out to a single fileserver folder in preparation for a reorganisation exercise.

ReportingServicesTools provides `Get-RsFolderContent`, although I'm not certain whether or not a folder is considered "content" or not, and if not what other command would give this.  Also, how do I pipe the results to the Add-Content command to write it to the file?

This is my first attempt which doesn't work:

```
Get-RsFolderContent -Proxy $proxy -RsFolder / | 
    WHERE TypeName -NotLike Report | 
        Add-Content S:\Reports\Download\DownloadFolderList.txt Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following...

```
Get-RsFolderContent -Proxy $proxy -RsFolder / -Recurse | 
where { $_.TypeName -eq 'Folder' } | 
Add-Content -Path 'S:\Reports\Download\DownloadFolderList.txt'
```

- Wrapped the predicate in your `WHERE-OBJECT` in braces.
- Changed the predicate to return a directory object
- Added the recurse switch so all folders are found
- Removed the `name` literal in the `Add-Content` call
- Specified the `path` parameter in the `Add-Content` call and wrapped the value in single quotes

Didn't test this. GL!

Comment: Thanks Adam.  I tried this and it didn't error as my own attempt had.  However, the file it produced contained only the following line repeated: 

Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1tserver_ReportService2010_asmx.CatalogItem

I'll see how I can alter it.  Any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: I’d need to see the output, but it looks like you figured it out! Congrats!

Answer (score 0):

This eventually gave me the folder list, sorted in alphabetical order:

Get-RsFolderContent -Proxy $proxy -RsFolder / -Recurse | 
where { $_.TypeName -eq 'Folder' } | Select –ExpandProperty Path | Sort-Object |
out-file -filepath 'S:\Reports\Download\DownloadFolderList.txt'